# Could not load assembly in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating a xamarin apps and for some reason I get the error below on runtime.

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlResourceIdAttribute' from assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.'
```

Comment: Try this: 1. Close Visual Studio.  2. Delete all `obj` and `bin` folders inside of your Xamarin project folder, 3. Launch Visual Studio again and open your project

Comment: I already did it and it doesn't work

Comment: try update your nuget package to the latest version and reload your project

Comment: If you create a new Xamarin Solution/Project, does that run okay?